# Can't play live YouTube videos on Ubuntu 20.04

Tags: 20.04, firefox, flash, youtube

> Your browser does not currently recognize any of the video formats available.
> Click here to visit our frequently asked questions about HTML5 video.

Above message is displayed.I use live USB Ubuntu 20.04 and used the Mozilla Firefox. Normal YouTube videos are playing without any issues. How to solve it? I tried to install Ubuntu restricted extras but failed.

Answer (score 5):

Had the same problem.

```
sudo apt-get install ffmpeg
```

Comment: yes this is the answer. I have to add tho. To anyone reading this, you need to restart firefox, reopen it and you will now be able to play live YouTube videos. Worked for me! OP should mark this as the answer and give all the credits.